# Cant understand how semantic UI elements work

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I recently decided to use some semantic `ui` elements with react but I can't understand how it works. Here are some examples :

I have this container element :

```css
.mainContainer{
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

**It works perfect**

But after that I got this button that is not rendering anything except if I put this before its name : `.ui.button`

So the full name, its like this

```css
.ui.button.modalButton{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

If I delete `.ui.button` its not going to work.

With modal I have another problem also it renders my css perfect but not the props that are describing in the docs.

So if I have this

```css
.modalHeader {
  text-align: center;  
}
```

Its going to render the center perfect but if I put the color prop its not going to do anything.

So whats happening exactly?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue

Comment: Does your button have `class='modalButton'`?  Or does it have `class='ui.button.modalButton'`?

Comment: Nono just modalButton in the className .